# What is stronger - WPA2 Enterprise with 2048 bit key, or Personal with 63 character passphrase?

Tags: cryptography, wifi, wpa2, wpa2-eap, wpa-enterprise

Which of the two following has a stronger cryptographic strength in withstanding brute-force attacks?

- WPA/WPA2 Enterprise using 2048-bit RSA public-key
- WPA/WPA2 Personal using 63-character Passphrase

Answer (score 42):

### Security from exhaustive search

Ignoring the benefits and drawbacks of each protocol and focusing exclusively on the difficulty of a brute force attack, the answer is that they are both *identical*. The reason for this is that the only difference between the two is how the key is derived. When using WPA2 Enterprise, a random 128-bit key is generated and exchanged using public key cryptography. For WPA2 Personal using a passphrase of any length, a 128-bit key is derived from the passphrase itself using a key-strengthening algorithm called [PBKDF2](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/16357/106285).<sup>*</sup> Regardless of how it is generated, the session key will have a keyspace of up to 2<sup>128</sup>. For a 63-character random passphrase, the entire 2<sup>128</sup> keyspace of the session key is used.

### Security from cryptanalysis

If on the other hand you are referring to *any* type of cryptoanalytic attack, the answer is that the WPA2 Enterprise option using RSA 2048 provides less security. RSA 2048 is [approximately equivalent](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8687/54184) to a 112-bit key. The reason for this is that attacking RSA is not done using brute force, but by attempting to factor a very large composite number. [RSA uses](https://hackernoon.com/how-does-rsa-work-f44918df914b?gi=5fb13db255cc) the so-called integer factorization problem, a problem in mathematics which states that, while it is easy to multiply two huge prime numbers, factoring the resulting composite number back into the original two prime numbers is *very, very hard*.<sup><sup>†</sup></sup>

The most effective algorithm for factoring large numbers is called [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve), which is significantly faster than an exhaustive search, but is still far too computationally-intensive to perform on realistic semiprimes. When you are using a 63-character passphrase on the other hand, it is directly converted into a 128-bit key by PBKDF2 using [4096 iterations of HMAC-SHA1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/28981/54184). If the 63-character passphrase is chosen randomly from a US keyboard with 95 printable keys, it gives a keyspace of 95<sup>63</sup>, which is far greater than 2<sup>128</sup> (it has the equivalent security of log<sub>2</sub>(95<sup>63</sup>) ≈ 413.9 bits). Because the session key is only 128 bits, the entire keyspace of the 63 keys is not used, only that of the 128-bit session key.

### Security in practice

In practice, WPA2 Enterprise using public key cryptography is more secure. This is not because it is more difficult to attack with cryptanalysis, but because it provides other security benefits such as [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy), which ensures that an attacker who compromises one session will not be able to then retroactively decrypt previously recorded sessions, because each key is generated randomly for each session. WPA2 Personal on the other hand uses the passphrase to derive the key, and as long as the passphrase remains the same, any data encrypted under that passphrase can be decrypted as soon as you learn what it is. Because WPA2 Enterprise allows the key to be generated entirely randomly, there is no risk of using a poor passphrase that can be broken.

It is often not easy to maintain a fully random 63-character password among multiple devices. If you are using the complete 95 character set from a US keyboard, you only need 20 random characters to fully utilize the entire keyspace of the cipher, as 95<sup>20</sup> is [just barely above](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20log2%2895%5En%29%20%3E=%20128%20over%20the%20integers) 2<sup>128</sup>. Adding more characters would only be useful if you expect them not to be entirely random.

You should be aware that [WPA3 has been announced](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/177236/106285). It is a new protocol which vastly improves wireless security. It provides individualized encryption even on open networks, allowing people to securely use hotel and airport hotspots without worrying about passive eavesdropping, and allowing people to share their key with guests without allowing them to read their traffic. It does this by dissociating the user-supplied key from the encryption. In other words, the key you provide is *only* used to authenticate yourself to the hotspot. Public key cryptography will automatically generate a per-use random session key. WPA3 comes with other improvements as well, such as a larger 192-bit key. The protocol will be slowly rolled out to new devices during 2018.

Note that I am assuming WPA2 is configured to use [CCMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCMP_%28cryptography%29) which uses AES128 in [CCM mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode), rather than the broken [TKIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Key_Integrity_Protocol) which uses the [much weaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security) RC4 stream cipher.

<sub>* It is slightly more complicated than this. The PSK is not directly plugged into the cipher after going through PBKDF2. Instead, a [4-way handshake](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/66008/106285) is done which relies on the secrecy of the PSK. It suffices to say that knowledge of the PSK allows anyone who has captured traffic (including the 4-way handshake) to decrypt the session.</sub>

<sub><sup>†</sup> Integer factorization is an open problem in mathematics. It is possible that a classical algorithm will be discovered that can factor a large semiprime in polynomial time. Additionally, quantum computers running [Shor's algorithm](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/09/quantum-cryptography-yesterday-today-and-tomorrow/) will do this in polynomial time. There are no publicly known cryptoanalytic quantum computers in production.</sub>

Comment: `For WPA2 Personal using a passphrase of the any length, a 128-bit key is derived from the passphrase itself using an algorithm called PBKDF2` - Everyday is a schoolday!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but given that the keyspace of 95^63 is greater than 2^128, wouldn't in theory a plaintext collision be possible where the 128 bit key after the 4K iterations could be derivable from multiple passphrases?

Comment: -1 for  "For WPA2 Personal using a passphrase of the any length, a 128-bit key is derived from the passphrase itself using an algorithm called PBKDF2. Regardless of how it is generated, the session key will have a keyspace of 2^128". The keyspace is directly dependent on the passphrase space in that it can be no bigger. So if the passphrase space is limited whether by length, choice or complexity (which is very likely btw. since few people will be typing in 63 random characters), than the keyspace is similarly limited.

Comment: "very, very hard" actually, the difficulty of prime factorisation is unknown. There are no known solutions that are easy to compute, but there's no proof that there aren't any. The suspicion is that it is easier than NPC though.

Comment: @nzall not only is it possible it is certain. While we don't know whether pbkdf2 or even just plain SHA2 is injective on say the space of short messages (length at most 256 bits) it's actually unlikely, and it certainly can't be injective on any space with is bigger.

Comment: @DRF The question was assuming a 63-character passphrase, so that's what I used to factor into that statement (since 95^63 > 2^128). I will clarify to reduce the ambiguity. Does it address your concerns?

Comment: @DRF Indeed, the pigeonhole principle applies to any hash function. Thankfully there are no known preimages for SHA-1 so it shouldn't matter in practice (for WPA2).

Comment: In a way. I think that one more important point is that I really don't see anyone using a random 63 character passphrase. Just typing that in is a non-trivial problem ignoring the fact that it's hard to remember and so will be on post-it some place most likely. It could be a quote in which case it's very likely to have much much smaller entropy, many orders less. The main point I was trying to make though is that the keyspace is determined by what you generate from and what the attacker can assume. If the 63 characters are names of your dogs .... well you get the idea.

Comment: And yes the collision is irrelevant you are right there of course. It would have relevance if we knew that SHA1 or PBKDF2 favored some outputs for larger lengths of input but that seems unlikely at best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75562/discussion-between-drf-and-forest).

Comment: Your description of WPA3 says: *the key you provide is only used to authenticate yourself to the hotspot, after which public key cryptography will automatically generate a per-use random session key*. Does it really happen in that order? I would think it would be more secure to first generate a session key using Diffie-Hellman key exchange or similar and then inside the encrypted session do authentication.

Comment: @kasperd That's a good point. I am not sure of the details of the WPA3 protocol. I've re-worded the statement.