# Why does linux cryptsetup use PBKDF2 instead of bcrypt?

Tags: cryptography, linux, bcrypt, pbkdf2

I've noticed that linux's cryptsetup utility by default uses the PBKDF2 for a key derivative function (KDF) versus using bcrypt, when bcrypt has more resistance to brute forcing from gpus. Why would cryptsetup use a technically less secure KDF, and opt for a high number of iterations?

Comment: What makes you think that PBKDF2 is "less secure" than bcrypt?

Comment: Just speculating, but it may have something to do with bcrypt's significantly higher memory usage and Linux's frequent usage in embedded environments, and that PBKDF2 is not inherently _less_ secure, it just requires more iterations to achieve the same security.

Comment: @MechMK1" when bcrypt has more resistance to brute forcing from gpus"

Comment: See this question [What's the advantage of using PBKDF2 vs SHA256 to generate an AES encryption key from a passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/16354/86735)

Comment: GPUs don't work, but the idea of using a large number of simple cores (compared to a small number of expensive, complex, energy inefficient cores like your PC has) [still applies](https://www.openwall.com/presentations/Passwords14-Energy-Efficient-Cracking/). Bcrypt is small enough to be easily parallelized, potentially improving cracker hash rates. (Even without ASICs; still with relatively inexpensive commodity hardware.) Bcrypt is absolutely better than PBKDF2, but if you have the resources available for better password hashing you should use something better.

Comment: Might be that whoever created it wanted something that could be FIPS 140 certified.  PBKDF2 is an approved FIPS 140 algorithm.  bcrypt is not.

Comment: You should ask the why to the authors, not to us. We can only create educated guesses. I don't think there is a lot of difference when it comes to security of PBKDF2 or bcrypt. Real differences are obtained when a true memory hard function is used like scrypt or a variant of Argon2.

Comment: Cryptsetup itself doesn't care about the KDF, so I assume you're talking about LUKS, which specifies PBKDF2. Anyway, LUKS2 now supports Argon2 (which is even better than bcrypt).